# Requested JSON parse failed in jquery ajax

Tags: jquery

I'm having my abc.html code at client side and pqr.java servlet at the server end on another domain.But when i try for the jquery ajax call using datatype jsonp i get the error "Requested JSON parse failed" even though my server cosol displays the correct output.Please help,urgent.Thanks in advance

Comment: show us your json and the code which is parsing json

Comment: check whether your request data is well formatted!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'had added this line already.My mistake was that i was not appending callback function name to my json response at the server end.
By the way thanks. I got the answer.

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-aj-jsonp1/wa-aj-jsonp1-pdf.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you had problems with your header.. try the following code

```
response.setContentType("application/json");
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though the OP found an answer, I would like to share a mistake I was doing. In my server side code I was sending 'text' as content-type. However, in the jquery ajax call (from frontend) I had set `dataType: 'json'`. This mismatch was causing the error on the website. However, it was working fine on the console. Here is an answer giving more details about contentType and dataType - https://stackoverflow.com/a/18701357/5576491