# Error 415: x-www-form-urlencoded versus JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, web-services

The web service accepts `application/json`, but `$.ajax()` with `dataType : 'json'` set just tries to send data as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. What's the trick here?

Comment: Checkout this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/18701357/1370442 notice you need to set contentType as well as dataType ;o)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dataType: 'json'` specifies that jQuery expects JSON *back* from the server ([see docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)). In order to specify that you are sending JSON, you need to add `contentType: "application/json"`.

Furthermore, jQuery cannot convert an object into JSON for you. If you are passing any object to `data`, you need to [stringify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191881/serializing-to-json-in-jquery) it yourself:

```
data: JSON.stringify(dataObject);
```

Comment: Thanks, JSON.stringify solved all pain of this day :)