# PHP AJAX datetime range probleme on SQL Query

Tags: javascript, php, sql-server, ajax, datetime

I have a big problem and I hope I will find the solution here. After 4 days of useless search I come here to ask for a solution.

Here is my problem. I use a SQL Server database and php as server side language with AJAX to send the params to the php server.

My web app must display a list of some data if user input some date range.

Here my html form code :

```
<form method="post" action="">

    <input type="text" placeholder="Start date : dd/mm/yyyy" id="date1" name="date1">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Date de fin : dd/mm/yyy" id="date2" name="date2">
    <input type="BUTTON" class="my-button" value="Show Data" onClick="LoadData()">

</form>
```

Here is my javascript function LoadData()

```
<script>
function LoadData(){
    var url = "json.php";

        var date1=document.getElementById('date1');
        var date2=document.getElementById('date2');
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

        var params= 'date1=' + date1 + '&date2=' + date2 ;
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        myFunction(xmlhttp.responseText);
                        }
                    }
        xmlhttp.open("POST", url, true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xmlhttp.send(params);


        function myFunction(response) {

        var arr = JSON.parse(response);
        var i; 
        var sum = 0;
        var out = "";               
        for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) 

        out += '<li><div class="news_desc"><table width="100%" border="1"><tr><td width="70%"><h4><a>' + 
                            arr[i].Name +
                            '</h4></td><td width="30%">' +
                            arr[i].Price +
                            '</td></tr><tr><td><p>' +
                            arr[i].Date +
                            '</p></td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr></table></div><div class="clear"> </div></li>' ;

                        }
        out += ''
        document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;

    }
        }

</script>
```

Here is my php script

```
if(isset($_POST['date1']) && isset($_POST['date2']) )
{
    $date1 = $_POST["date1"];
    $date2 = $_POST["date2"];

        $db_name  = "DATABASE";
        $hostname = 'IO-SD-L1';
        $username = '';
        $password = '';

       // connect to the database
        $dbh = new PDO( "sqlsrv:Server= $hostname ; Database = $db_name ", $username, $password);

        $sql = "SELECT name, CAST( DateReg AS DATE ) AS dateIn, price FROM TBL_USERS
                WHERE CAST( DateReg AS DATE )BETWEEN '".$date1."'AND '".$date2."'";

     // the DateReg is datetime type

        $stmt = $dbh->prepare( $sql );
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );

        foreach ($result as $row){
        $return[]=array('Name'=>$row['name'],
                    'Date'=>$row['dateIn'],
                    'Price'=>$row['price']);

}
$dbh = null;

echo json_encode($return); }
```

If I put the date range directly in the code like `date1="12/12/2011" ; date2="11/12/2014"` it works perfectly but if I chose the date range by user input in the two date textfield and click on the Show data button, I don't get anything.

Comment: Any particular reason you're not using jQuery to do this?

Comment: probably because jQuery is not the hammer for every nail @Daan :)

Comment: Please could you show me how? some codes samples?

Comment: @JayBlanchard No true but in this case jQuery will do.

Comment: If the OP is not loading jQuery and he can do it in minimal JavaScript then they have no reason to load jQuery @Daan. Sure, it will do, but if all the OP needs to do is this one thing the overhead is not worth it.

Answer (score 1):

So you are saying that when you enter a date (hard coded) it works perfectly; but when you enter the same date via a textbox control; it doesn't work?  If so, I would do this:  `console.log(params)` after you get your input data.  You will find that it is not the same as you think; I suspect.

If you wish to use jQuery instead (since it simplifies the xmlhttp handlers...  Try like this:

```
var  formData = "name=johndoe&age=24";  // name value pair
// or...
var formData = { name : "johndoe", age : "24" }; // object

$.ajax({
    url : "/your/url/goes/here.php",
    type: "POST",
    data : formData,
    // if you wish to send the object as JSON, you will need to do this instead of the above...
    // data: JSON.stringify(formData),
    // you will also need to uncomment the next line
    // contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
    {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {
        console.log(errorThrown);
    }
});
```

Ref. [What is content-type and datatype in an AJAX request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18701282/what-is-content-type-and-datatype-in-an-ajax-request)

Comment: I get this error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Comment: So this is what was returned from your server?  Change the error function to this to be sure `console.log('Server error: '+errorThrown);`

Answer (score 0):

I think your function not called on button click.

Check it just add

```
alert('check');
```

I first line in function body.

Also tray change onClick="LoadData()"  to onClick="LoadData"

Comment: The function is properly called button onClick

Comment: [Stop using alert() for troubleshooting.](http://stravid.com/en/stop-the-javascript-alert-madness/)

Answer (score 0):

If your DATE contains TIME information, like `11/12/2014 13:30` for example. This will FAIL in the clause `BETWEEN 10/12/2014 AND 11/12/2014`   (using UK dd/mm/yyyy format).  You must strip the TIME portion for the BETWEEN to work in the way you need it to here

Comment: Do you know what date format you are using? US or UK?  Because your code "Date de fin : dd/mm/yyy" looks incomplete.  SQL Server uses mm/dd/yyyy format or easier if you use 'yyyy-mm-dd' for SQL Server

Comment: My SQL server is a french server so I think the date format will be in dd/mm/yyyy format. My date de fin is juste a place holder, the fourth y is just missing:typing error.

Answer (score 0):

My LoadData()

```
 <script>
function LoadData(){
    var url = "json.php?";

    var date1=document.getElementById('date1');
    var date2=document.getElementById('date2');
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    var params= 'date1=' + date1 + '&date2=' + date2 ;

         xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                myFunction(xmlhttp.responseText);
                }
            }


            xmlhttp.open("GET", url+params, true);
            xmlhttp.send(null); 

    function myFunction(response) {

    var arr = JSON.parse(response);
    var i; 
    var sum = 0;
    var out = "";               
    for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) 

    out += '<li><div class="news_desc"><table width="100%" border="1"><tr><td width="70%"><h4><a>' + 
                        arr[i].Name +
                        '</h4></td><td width="30%">' +
                        arr[i].Price +
                        '</td></tr><tr><td><p>' +
                        arr[i].Date +
                        '</p></td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr></table></div><div class="clear"> </div></li>' ;

                    }
    out += ''
    document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;

}
    }
```

My Php code

```
if(isset($_GET['date1']) && isset($_GET['date2']) )
{



$date1 = $_GET["date1"];
$date2 = $_GET["date2"];

$start_date = new DateTime($date1);
$end_date = new DateTime($date2);

$start_date = $start_date->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s');
$end_date= $end_date->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s');

    $db_name  = "DATABASE";
    $hostname = 'IO-SD-L1';
    $username = '';
    $password = '';

   // connect to the database
    $dbh = new PDO( "sqlsrv:Server= $hostname ; Database = $db_name ", $username, $password);

    $sql = "SELECT name, CAST( DateReg AS DATE ) AS dateIn, price FROM TBL_USERS
            WHERE CAST( DateReg AS DATE )BETWEEN '".$start_date."'AND '".$end_date."'";

 // the DateReg is datetime type

    $stmt = $dbh->prepare( $sql );
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );

    foreach ($result as $row){
    $return[]=array('Name'=>$row['name'],
                'Date'=>$row['dateIn'],
                'Price'=>$row['price']);

}

$dbh = null;

echo json_encode($return); }
```

I hope this will help someone in future

Answer (score 0):

```html
I recorded data on the table.  when i execute no errorsand no result.

My customers order table here is below

create table customer_orders 
(
order_date timestamp,
order_id int(10) not null primary key,
customer_id int(10),
due_amount int(100),
invoice_no int(100),
qty int(10),
size text,
order_status text 
)

Here is below my my_orders.php source code
<?php

include("includes/db_connection.php");

 ?>

<body style="margin:20px auto"> 



<center><!--center Starts-->

  <h1 class="row header" style="text-align:center;color:green"> My Orders </h1>

  <p class="lead" style="text-align:center;color:green"> your orders on one place. </p>
  <p class="text-muted"> If you have any questions, please feel free to <a href="../contact.php" > Contact Us, </a> our customer service center is working for you 8/5.</p>
  
</center><!--center Ends-->

<hr>

<form class="form-inline"><!--form-inline Starts-->

<div class="col-md-3 input-group " ><!--col-md-3 Starts-->
  
  <input type="text" name="from_date" id="from_date" class="form-control" placeholder="From Date">

  <label class="input-group-addon btn" for="from_date">
       <span class="fa fa-calendar"></span>
</label>

</div><!--col-md-3 Ends-->

<div class="col-md-3 input-group"><!--col-md-3 Starts-->

<input type="text" name="to_date" id="to_date" class="form-control" placeholder="To Date ">

<label class="input-group-addon btn" for="to_date">
       <span class="fa fa-calendar"></span>
</label>

</div><!--col-md-3 Ends-->

<div class="col-md-5 input-group"><!--col-md-5 Starts-->

<input type="button" name="filter" id="filter" value="Filter" class="btn btn-primary btn-md" >

</div><!--col-md-5 Ends-->

<div style="clear:both"></div>

</form><!--form-inline Ends-->

<hr>

<div class="table-responsive" ><!--table-responsive Starts-->

  <table class="table  table-bordered table-hover" id="my_orders" ><!--table  table-bordered table-hover Starts-->

    <thead><!--thead Starts-->

    <tr>
      
      <th style="text-align: left; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; padding-left: 2px; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px;">ON </th>
      <th style="text-align: left; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; padding-left: 2px; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px;">Invoice No </th>
      <th style="text-align: left; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; padding-left: 2px; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px;">Qty </th> 
      <th style="text-align: left; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; padding-left: 2px; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px;">ETB </th>
      <th style="text-align: left; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; padding-left: 2px; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px;">Order Date </th>
      <th style="text-align: left; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; padding-left: 2px; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px;">Status </th>
      <th style="text-align: left; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; padding-left: 2px; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px;">Assigned</th>
      <th style="text-align: left; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; padding-left: 2px; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px;">  Wait me for </th>

      <th style="text-align: left; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; padding-left: 2px; padding-right: 2px; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; "> Satisfied </th>
      

    </tr>

    </thead><!--thead Ends-->
    
 <tbody><!--tbody Starts-->

      <?php

      $customer_session = $_SESSION['customer_username'];

      $get_customer = "select * from customers where customer_username='$customer_session'";

      $run_customer = mysqli_query($con,$get_customer);

      $row_customer = mysqli_fetch_array($run_customer);

      $customer_id = $row_customer['customer_id'];

      $get_orders = "SELECT * FROM customer_orders WHERE customer_id='$customer_id' ORDER BY order_date ASC";

      $run_orders = mysqli_query($con,$get_orders);

      if( mysqli_num_rows($run_orders) > 0)

    {

      $i = 0;

      $total = 0;
    
    while ( $row_orders = mysqli_fetch_array($run_orders)) {

      $order_id = $row_orders['order_id'];

        $due_amount = $row_orders['due_amount'];

        $invoice_no = $row_orders['invoice_no'];

        $qty = $row_orders['qty'];

        $size = $row_orders['size'];

        $date = substr($row_orders['order_date'],0, 11);

        $order_date = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($date));

        $order_status = $row_orders['order_status'];

        $i++;

        $total += $due_amount;

        if($order_status=='pending'){

          $order_status = "Pending";
        }

        elseif($order_status=='Accepted'){

          $order_status = "Approve";
        }


        else {

          $order_status = "Rejected";
        }

       echo '<tr> <td style="text-align: center">  '.$i.'</td>

              <td>  '.$invoice_no.'</td>

              <td style="text-align: center"> '.$qty.'</td>

              <td style="text-align: center">  '.$due_amount.'</td>

              <td> '.$order_date.'</td>

              <td>  '.$order_status.'</td>

              

              <td>  Seyoum </td>

              <td style="text-align: center"> 30  </td>

              <td>  <select name="satisfied" width="5" height="16" padding-left="0" padding-right="0">

              <option> Yes </option>

              <option> 50% </option>

              <option> No </option>

              </select> <a href="order.php?customer_id=<?php echo $customer_id; ?>" class="btn btn-primary btn btn-xs" > Send</a></td>

              
          </tr><!--tr Ends-->';

}

}

    else {

      $output .= '

      <tr>

      <td colspan="5" > No order found </td>

      </tr>

      ';
    }

      ?>

      
    </tbody><!--tbody Ends-->

    <tfoot><!-- tfoot Starts-->


                <tr >

                  <th colspan="6" style="text-align: center;font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; border: 1px solid #999999; border-radius: 0px;" class="alert alert-success " >My Total Orders and Costs Summary  </th>

                  <th colspan="3" style="font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold;  border-left: 0px; border-top: 1px solid #999999; border-bottom: 1px solid #999999; border-right: 1px solid #999999; border-radius: 0px;" class="alert alert-success " >My Satisfied Status on Services That I Got </th> 
            
                </tr>

                <tr>

                  <th colspan="3" class="alert alert-info" style="text-align: center;font-size: 13px; font-weight: bold; border-top: none; border-left: 1px solid #999999; border-bottom: 1px solid #999999; border-right: 1px solid #999999; border-radius: 0px;"> My Total Orders in Qty  </th>
                  
                  <th colspan="3" class="alert alert-info"style="text-align: center;font-size: 13px; font-weight: bold; border-top: none; border-bottom: 1px solid #999999; border-right: 1px solid #999999; border-radius: 0px;"> My Orders Total Costs in ETB </th>

                  <th colspan="1" class="alert alert-info" style="text-align: center;font-size: 13px; font-weight: bold; border-top: none; border-bottom: 1px solid #999999; border-right: 1px solid #999999; border-radius: 0px;"> Satisfied  </th> 

                  <th colspan="1" class="alert alert-info" style="text-align: center;font-size: 13px; font-weight: bold;
                   border-top: none; border-bottom: 1px solid #999999; border-right: 1px solid #999999; border-radius: 0px;"> Half(50%) </th>

                  <th colspan="1" style="text-align: center; font-size: 13px; font-weight: bold; border-top: none; border-left: none; border-bottom: 1px solid #999999; border-right: 1px solid #999999; border-radius: 0px;" class="alert alert-info" > Unsatisfied </th>  

                              

                </tr>

                <tr>




                  <th colspan="3" style="text-align: center; ext-align: center;font-size: 13px; font-weight: bold; border-top: none; border-left: 1px solid #999999; border-bottom: 1px solid #999999; border-right: 1px solid #999999; border-radius: 0px;" class="alert alert-warning" ><?php  echo $i; ?> </th>

                  <th colspan="3" style="text-align: center; font-size: 13px; font-weight: bold; border-top: none; border-bottom: 1px solid #999999; border-right: 1px solid #999999; border-radius: 0px;" class="alert alert-warning" > <?php  echo  $total; ?></th>

                  <th colspan="1" style="text-align: center;text-align: center;font-size: 13px; font-weight: bold; border-top: none; border-bottom: 1px solid #999999; border-right: 1px solid #999999; border-radius: 0px;" class="alert alert-warning" ><?php  echo ""; ?> </th>  

                  <th colspan="1" style="text-align: center; border-top: none; border-bottom: 1px solid #999999; border-right: 1px solid #999999; border-radius: 0px;" class="alert alert-warning" ><?php  echo "" ;?> </th> 

                  <th colspan="1" style="text-align: center; border-top: none; border-left: none; border-bottom: 1px solid #999999; border-right: 1px solid #999999; border-radius: 0px;" class="alert alert-warning" ><?php  echo "" ;?> </th> 


                </tr>
                            

              </tfoot><!-- tfoot Ends-->

  </table><!--table  table-bordered table-hover Ends-->

</div><!--table-responsive Ends-->

</body> 

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#my_orders').dataTable();

    $.datepicker.setDefaults({

     dateFormat:'dd-mm-yy'

     });
  
    $(function (){

    $('#from_date').datepicker(); 

    $('#to_date').datepicker();

});

    $('#filter').click(function(){

      var from_date = $('#from_date').val();

      var to_date = $('#to_date').val();

      if(from_date != '' && to_date != '')

      {
        $.ajax({

          url:"filter.php",

          method:"POST",

          data:{from_date:from_date, to_date:to_date},

          success:function(data) {

            $('#my_orders').html(data);
            
          }

        });


      }

      else {

        alert("Please select date")
      }


    });
   
});

</script>

Here is below my filter.php source code

<?php

session_start();

include("includes/db_connection.php");

 ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> OISRMS | Online ICT Support Request Management System </title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">

</head> 

<body>

<div class="table-responsive" ><!--table-responsive Starts-->

  <table class="table  table-bordered table-hover"><!--table  table-bordered table-hover Starts-->

    <thead><!--thead Starts-->

    <tr>
      
      <th style="text-align: left; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; padding-left: 2px; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px;">ON </th>
      <th style="text-align: left; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; padding-left: 2px; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px;">Invoice No </th>
      <th style="text-align: left; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; padding-left: 2px; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px;">Qty </th> 
      <th style="text-align: left; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; padding-left: 2px; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px;">ETB </th>
      <th style="text-align: left; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; padding-left: 2px; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px;">Order Date </th>
      <th style="text-align: left; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; padding-left: 2px; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px;">Status </th>
      <th style="text-align: left; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; padding-left: 2px; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px;">Assigned</th>
      <th style="text-align: left; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; padding-left: 2px; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px;">  Wait me for </th>

      <th style="text-align: left; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; padding-left: 2px; padding-right: 2px; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; "> Satisfied </th>
      

    </tr>

    </thead><!--thead Ends-->
    
 <tbody><!--tbody Starts-->

      <?php

   if(isset($_POST["from_date"], $_POST["to_date"])) {

    $customer_session = $_SESSION['customer_username'];

    $get_customer = "select * from customers where customer_username='$customer_session'";

    $run_customer = mysqli_query($con,$get_customer);

    $row_customer = mysqli_fetch_array($run_customer);

      $customer_id = $row_customer['customer_id'];

      $get_orders = "SELECT * FROM customer_orders WHERE customer_id='$customer_id' AND order_date BETWEEN '".$_POST["from_date"]."' AND '".$_POST["to_date"]."' ";

      $run_orders = mysqli_query($con,$get_orders);

    $i = 0;

    $total = 0;

      if( mysqli_num_rows($run_orders) > 0)

    {

    while ( $row_orders = mysqli_fetch_array($run_orders)) {

      $order_id = $row_orders['order_id'];

        $due_amount = $row_orders['due_amount'];

        $invoice_no = $row_orders['invoice_no'];

        $qty = $row_orders['qty'];

        $size = $row_orders['size'];

        $date = substr($row_orders['order_date'],0, 11);

        $order_date = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($date));

        $order_status = $row_orders['order_status'];

        $i++;

        $total += $due_amount;

        if($order_status=='pending'){

          $order_status = "Pending";
        }

        elseif($order_status=='Accepted'){

          $order_status = "Approve";
        }


        else {

          $order_status = "Rejected";
        }

       echo '<tr> <td style="text-align: center">  '.$i.'</td>

              <td>  '.$invoice_no.'</td>

              <td style="text-align: center"> '.$qty.'</td>

              <td style="text-align: center">  '.$due_amount.'</td>

              <td> '.$order_date.'</td>

              <td>  '.$order_status.'</td>

              

              <td>  Seyoum </td>

              <td style="text-align: center"> 30  </td>

              <td>  <select name="satisfied" width="5" height="16" padding-left="0" padding-right="0">

              <option> Yes </option>

              <option> 50% </option>

              <option> No </option>

              </select> <a href="order.php?customer_id=<?php echo $customer_id; ?>" class="btn btn-primary btn btn-xs" > Send</a></td>

              
          </tr><!--tr Ends-->';

}

}

    else {

      echo '

      <tr>

      <td style "text-align: center;" colspan="9" > No order found </td>

      </tr>

      ';
    }

}

      ?>

      
    </tbody><!--tbody Ends-->

    <tfoot><!-- tfoot Starts-->


                <tr >

                  <th colspan="6" style="text-align: center;font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; border: 1px solid #999999; border-radius: 0px;" class="alert alert-success " >My Total Orders and Costs Summary  </th>

                  <th colspan="3" style="font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold;  border-left: 0px; border-top: 1px solid #999999; border-bottom: 1px solid #999999; border-right: 1px solid #999999; border-radius: 0px;" class="alert alert-success " >My Satisfied Status on Services That I Got </th> 
            
                </tr>

                <tr>

                  <th colspan="3" class="alert alert-info" style="text-align: center;font-size: 13px; font-weight: bold; border-top: none; border-left: 1px solid #999999; border-bottom: 1px solid #999999; border-right: 1px solid #999999; border-radius: 0px;"> My Total Orders in Qty  </th>
                  
                  <th colspan="3" class="alert alert-info"style="text-align: center;font-size: 13px; font-weight: bold; border-top: none; border-bottom: 1px solid #999999; border-right: 1px solid #999999; border-radius: 0px;"> My Orders Total Costs in ETB </th>

                  <th colspan="1" class="alert alert-info" style="text-align: center;font-size: 13px; font-weight: bold; border-top: none; border-bottom: 1px solid #999999; border-right: 1px solid #999999; border-radius: 0px;"> Satisfied  </th> 

                  <th colspan="1" class="alert alert-info" style="text-align: center;font-size: 13px; font-weight: bold;
                   border-top: none; border-bottom: 1px solid #999999; border-right: 1px solid #999999; border-radius: 0px;"> Half(50%) </th>

                  <th colspan="1" style="text-align: center; font-size: 13px; font-weight: bold; border-top: none; border-left: none; border-bottom: 1px solid #999999; border-right: 1px solid #999999; border-radius: 0px;" class="alert alert-info" > Unsatisfied </th>  

                              

                </tr>

                <tr>




                  <th colspan="3" style="text-align: center; ext-align: center;font-size: 13px; font-weight: bold; border-top: none; border-left: 1px solid #999999; border-bottom: 1px solid #999999; border-right: 1px solid #999999; border-radius: 0px;" class="alert alert-warning" ><?php  echo $i; ?> </th>

                  <th colspan="3" style="text-align: center; font-size: 13px; font-weight: bold; border-top: none; border-bottom: 1px solid #999999; border-right: 1px solid #999999; border-radius: 0px;" class="alert alert-warning" > <?php  echo  $total; ?></th>

                  <th colspan="1" style="text-align: center;text-align: center;font-size: 13px; font-weight: bold; border-top: none; border-bottom: 1px solid #999999; border-right: 1px solid #999999; border-radius: 0px;" class="alert alert-warning" ><?php  echo ""; ?> </th>  

                  <th colspan="1" style="text-align: center; border-top: none; border-bottom: 1px solid #999999; border-right: 1px solid #999999; border-radius: 0px;" class="alert alert-warning" ><?php  echo "" ;?> </th> 

                  <th colspan="1" style="text-align: center; border-top: none; border-left: none; border-bottom: 1px solid #999999; border-right: 1px solid #999999; border-radius: 0px;" class="alert alert-warning" ><?php  echo "" ;?> </th> 


                </tr>
                            

              </tfoot><!-- tfoot Ends-->

  </table><!--table  table-bordered table-hover Ends-->

</div><!--table-responsive Ends-->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation around why this would work.  Currently there's no context.