# Store on PHP variables sent by Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am creating a DDBB Insert trough $.ajax:

```
$(document).on('click','.submitMessage', function(){
    content=$('textarea').val();
    img=$('#messageImg').val();
    stdMsg=$('.ms_stdMsg').val();
    prefix=$('.prefix').val();
    phone=$('.cuadroTelefono').val();

    $.ajax({
        url: "../actions/newMessage.php",
        type: "POST", 
        data:{ms_content:content, ms_img:img,ms_prefix:prefix,ms_phone:phone},
        contentType: false, 
        cache: false,  
        processData:false, 
        success: function(data) 
        {   
            alert("Enviado");
        }
    });
});
```

And this is the way I receive code on `newMessage.php`:

```
$ms_content = $_POST['ms_content'];
$ms_img = $_POST['ms_img'];
$ms_prefix = $_POST['ms_prefix'];
$ms_phone = $_POST['ms_phone'];
```

Console gives an error

> Notice: Undefined index: ms_content in C:...\newMessage.php on line 9

one for each variable passed (I have ommited entire URL)

As the posted information is an object, I guess I must decode it someway on PHP, but trying:

```
$ms_content = json_decode($_POST['ms_content']);
```

...has neither workd

Comment: you have not given any id or class in `$('textarea').val()`

Comment: That wouldn't be necessary if there was only one textarea @Vicky

Comment: you have taken `ms_content` twice in php variable check it

Comment: Have you watched the request / response in the browser's console? Did you realize you're putting the same info in `$ms_content` and `$ms_img`? BTW, an image will not upload via AJAX like this, you're not trying to do that are you? Do you have any errors in your console (like not declaring `var` before each variable?

Comment: @JayBlanchard, image is preuploaded. This passes only its URL. I have setted correclty the duplicity of ms_content on PHP.

Comment: Is `content` set before you send it?

Comment: @JayBlanchard yes. I have alerted all variables before sending and all do have their content.

Comment: Do you see `content` being passed in the request / response window?

Comment: Nope. On the window it says an object is being posted: [object Object]

Comment: Do a `var_dump($_POST['ms_content'])` in your PHP to see what you get.

Comment: Open the Network tab of your console (F12 is all major browsers) and watch the AJAX request. Make sure you're seeing all your variables being posted

Comment: @Machavity I dont see them, only OBJECT. Please read messages before.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I have alerted the result of the var_dump and it gives back the entire ms_content string. So it catches it correclty.

Comment: An `alert()` doesn't work in the PHP code. What do you mean you "alerted the result"? And what is Line 9?

Comment: I have setted an echo with the var_dump on PHP, stored it on the $ajax response (data) and alerted it

Comment: Line 9 is the line from the file newMessage.php where is the variable value storing: $ms_content = $_POST['ms_content'];

Comment: Change `contentType: false` to `contentType: text` in your AJAX function.

Comment: I have tried dataType : "text", also combined with contentType: "application/json" but none of these gave me result. I keep looking for this, here must be the issue

Comment: @JayBlanchard solved: $.post('../actions/newMessage.php',{ms_content:content, ms_img:img,ms_prefix:prefix,ms_phone:phone})

Comment: That is what you have in your original post. How is that different?

Comment: there are many differences: it is $.post, it only has url and data, etc... After trying hundreds of variations this worked for me

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the data that you are sending with contentType parameter. [For more references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18701282/what-is-content-type-and-datatype-in-an-ajax-request)

Comment: I am about to check this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(document).on('click','.submitMessage', function(){
        content=$('textarea').val();
        img=$('#messageImg').val();
        stdMsg=$('.ms_stdMsg').val();
        prefix=$('.prefix').val();
        phone=$('.cuadroTelefono').val();

        $.ajax({
            url: "../actions/newMessage.php",
            type: "POST", 
            data:{ms_content:content, ms_img:img,ms_prefix:prefix,ms_phone:phone},
            cache: false,              
            success: function(data) 
            {   
                alert("Enviado");
            }
        });
    });
```

Please remove `processData:false, contentType: false` and then try.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this $_REQUEST instead of $_POST in your php file.

```
$ms_content = $_REQUEST['ms_content'];
```

Instead of

```
$ms_content = $_POST['ms_content'];
```

Second Maybe due to url path

try giving full url path.

Third

Provide a contentType.

Answer (score -2):

I think you have to access the $_GET parameters because jquery documentation says:

> data
>   Type: PlainObject or String or Array
>   Data to be sent to the server. It is converted to a query string, if not already a string. It's appended to the url for GET-requests. See processData option to prevent this automatic processing. Object must be Key/Value pairs. If value is an Array, jQuery serializes multiple values with same key based on the value of the traditional setting (described below).

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

So you will get your data  with

```
$ms_img = $_GET['ms_img'];
```

Comment: Hi Rene.- No, there's a POST way to get this info.

Comment: On the page you linked check out **method** and you'll see you can set AJAX to POST, which he did. **type** is the older way of doing it

Comment: Okay i think i missinterpreted the description to only append it to the GET-request, but if i read it again, one could interpret it that only for GET-requests its appended to the url

Comment: The comment you're referring to is there to let you know how it will behave in `GET` situations. Regardless, it's not an answer to the OP