# MVC5 Returning a Generic List of Objects via Jquery Ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to retrieve a list of objects via jQuery Ajax

I have a controller Method like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetAllStates(string listname = "")
{
     clsDdl ddl = new clsDdl();
     List<clsDdl> retval = new List<clsDdl>();
     ddl.id = "1";
     ddl.value = "Dropdown1";
     ddl.status = "DDL Status";
     ddl.attributes = "First Dropdown Text";
     retval.Add(ddl);

     //return retval;
     return Json(new
     {
         list = retval
     }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Heres my Dropdown class that I am trying to return

```
public class clsDdl
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string attributes { get; set; }
}
```

Code in my view looks like this

```
 function LoadListItems (options) {

 var listname = options.listname;

$.ajax({
         type: "GET",
         url: url,
         data: JSON.stringify({
             listname: listname
         }),
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         async: true,
         success: function (result) {
            alert(result[0].value);
         },
         error: function (xhr, status, err) {
           alert(err.toString(), 'Error - LoadListItemsHelper');
         }
       });
```

My controller action is being hit. But the alert is always 'Undefined'. 
I have also tried

```
 success: function (data) {
                 var result = data.d;
                 for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                 alert(result[i].attributes);
                 }
```

No Success there either. What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: It looks like you are returning JSON inside a named property called list. What do you get for `alert(data.list);`?

Comment: I added this code

 success: function (data) {
                    var result = data.list;
                    alert(data.list);
                    alert(result.length);

The alert is 'Undefined' the second alert gives the error 'Unable to get property 'length' of undefined or null reference

Comment: When you receive the json in your browser can you analyze the response if it hsa something, if is empty you should start too see why is not returning to the view correctly

Comment: Thanks for the hint on console and response. Solved my problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1.**
You are returning JSON from the server.
You have to set `dataType` in Ajax request to `json`

1. contentType --> Data sending to server
2. dataType --> data returned from Server

[What is content-type and datatype in an AJAX request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18701282/what-is-content-type-and-datatype-in-an-ajax-request)

```
      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: url,
        data: JSON.stringify({  listname: listname }),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

//HERE
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (result) {
              alert(result[0].value);
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, err) {
               alert(err.toString(), 'Error - LoadListItemsHelper');
        }
    });
```

**2.**

You are returning

```
return new Json(new {list = retval}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

In `success: function(result)`

You can access the list like this:     `result.list[index]`

```
success: function (result) {

      for(var i =0; i < result.list.length; i++){

         alert(result.list[i].value);
         alert(result.list[i].status);
      }
}
```

**EDIT** Based on  Aivan Monceller 's comments you can do this:

As you are sending `GET` you don't need the

```
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
```

So you can write you Ajax like this:

```
      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: url,
        data: {  listname: listname },

//HERE
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (result) {
              alert(result[0].value);
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, err) {
               alert(err.toString(), 'Error - LoadListItemsHelper');
        }
    });
```

Comment: I made changes according to your suggestion. Thank you for the link by the way, very helpful.

The error I am getting is

SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

I am looking into this but if you have a suggestion, please feel free to share...

Comment: What response are you getting from the server? Do console.log(result) in your success function

Comment: Also you don't have to do this `data: JSON.stringify({  listname: listname })` . You can simply do `data:{ listname: listname }`

Comment: having said that I don't think you need this `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"` , since `listname` is a `GET` parameter

Comment: @AivanMonceller you are correct on both counts. Thanks so much.

Comment: @DawoodAwan thanks for the comprehensive response, it ultimately helped me solve the problem. Thanks again...