# Ajax GET request not working with Flask

Tags: jquery, python, ajax

I am taking in bunch of inputs from the user in html which I am then passing on to ajax query to get the response.

```
$.ajax({
  url:"http://0.0.0.0:8080/getReport",
  type:"GET",
  data:JSON.stringify(out),
  dataType:"json",
  contentType:"application/json"
})
```

Here is the Flask code that serves the above request.

```
@app.route('/getReport', methods=['GET'])
def report():
    return Response('this is a sample response')
```

The above method is not able to find the route to the 'report' with get. However, it is able to find it in POST request.

This is the log that I am getting

```
  127.0.0.1 - - [25/Apr/2016 13:00:03] "GET /getReport?{%22insertion_id%22:%22%22,%22start%22:%22%22,%22end%22:%22%22} HTTP/1.1" 400 -
```

Bad Request.. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: you are using `JSON` as URL parameters, why?

Comment: I don't think Flask accepts json data from client. You should send data as urlencoded, like `data: {'key': 'val',}`. No need to set `dataType` and `contentType` options.

Comment: You should serialize form data and not specify the dataType or contentType.  Send across and it should work fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A GET request does not have a `contentType` <sup>(*)</sup> and it isn't JSON-encoded, but URL-encoded (plain, regular key-value pairs).

This means you can simply go with jQuery's default.

```
$.get("http://0.0.0.0:8080/getReport", out).done(function (data) {
    // request finished
});
```

which will result in a request like:

```
GET /getReport?insertion_id=&start=&end= HTTP/1.1
```

This will be easily understood by the server.

---

<sup>(*)</sup> That's because the `Content-Type` header determines the type of the request body. GET requests do not have a request body.

Comment: Thanks!! It helped me in my understanding!