# jquery Ajax Doesn't Send JSON Data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I am trying to send an ajax send request, but it always goes into `error`.

```
$('form#contactForm button.submit').click(function () {

            var contactName = $('#contactForm #contactName').val();
            var contactEmail = $('#contactForm #contactEmail').val();
            var contactSubject = $('#contactForm #contactSubject').val();
            var contactMessage = $('#contactForm #contactMessage').val();

            var data = {
                'contactName': contactName,
                'contactEmail': contactEmail,
                'contactSubject': contactSubject,
                'contactMessage': contactMessage
            };

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/",
                data: data,
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: "application/json",
                success: function (msg) {
                    alert('success message: ' + msg);
                    if (msg == 'OK') {
                        $('#image-loader').fadeOut();
                        $('#message-warning').hide();
                        $('#contactForm').fadeOut();
                        $('#message-success').fadeIn();
                        $('#contactForm button.submit').prop('disabled', true);
                    }
                    else {
                        $('#image-loader').fadeOut();
                        $('#message-warning').html(msg);
                        $('#message-warning').fadeIn();
                    }

                },
                error: function (err) {
                    if (contactName.length === 0 || contactEmail.length === 0 || contactSubject.length === 0 ||
                        contactMessage.length === 0) {
                        $('#message-warning').html('Please check form once again.');
                        $('#message-warning').fadeIn();
                        event.preventDefault();
                    }
                    alert('inside error: ' + err.message);
                }
            });
            return false;
});
```

This always shows `alert('inside error: ' + err.message);`in `error`.I also tried `data: JSON.stringify(data)`and it didn't work either. Is there a problem with `data`variable? Where is the problem?

Network tab:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:3000/
Request Method:POST
Status Code:400 Bad Request
Remote Address:[::1]:3000
Response Headers
view source
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:24
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Sun, 23 Oct 2016 00:12:43 GMT
ETag:W/"18-9LwX+BuZqYnTTqGm6GcNuA"
X-Powered-By:Express
Request Headers
view source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:102
Content-Type:application/json
Host:localhost:3000
Origin:http://localhost:3000
Referer:http://localhost:3000/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.71 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Request Payload
contactName=My+Name&contactEmail=email%40email.com&contactSubject=My+Subject&contactMessage=My+Message
```

backend post

```
router.post('/', function (req, res) {
    if (typeof req.body.contactName === 'undefined' || typeof req.body.contactEmail === 'undefined' ||
        typeof req.body.contactSubject === 'undefined' || typeof req.body.contactMessage === 'undefined' ||
        !validator.isEmail(req.body.contactEmail)) {
        return res.status(400).send('error');
    }
    mail.sendMail(req.body.contactName, req.body.contactEmail, req.body.contactSubject, req.body.contactMessage);
    return res.status(200).send('okay');
});
```

Comment: What is the error ? Check the response of the ajax call also

Comment: Hard to say, request looks ok. Go to the developer tools in your browser and check in the Network tab if you pass the data along with your request. And check what the backend returns because if the error function triggers, that means the backend returns something other than 200.

Comment: You put `url: "/"`, are you sure this is the page you want to call?

Comment: @nicovank yes, my contact form is on my homepage.

Comment: @KrzysztofDąbrowski I have just checked the status and it was 200. Message was also sent, but ajax still shows error alert.

Comment: @Shyju err.message just says "Undefined"

Comment: Try removing `dataType: 'json'` - the response doesn't look like JSON

Comment: @Munchmallow because the first argument of the error function is the XHR object. What is the value of the second argument?

Comment: Well your status code says it all: `Status Code:400 Bad Request`.

Comment: I added network tab. 
If I set data as JSON.stringtify(data), I get status 200, but still request shows `err.message`and it is `undefined`. If l set data as `data`, request shows 400.

Comment: You shouldn't need to JSON stringily your data: your data is already a JS object, there is no need to convert any further. What code is handling the incoming POST request at the `/` url?

Comment: Added backend part. 
@Terry It gets request and sends it to `sendMail` function which contains 'nodemailer' for sending mail via Outlook.

Comment: your URL where you are  posting data does it have a method to consume post request?

Comment: have you debug in your backend? you can  insert a break point right before your request handler function. And see what is included in your variable `req.body`.

Comment: Note that the server's responses – `.send('error')` and `.send('okay')` – aren't valid JSON for `dataType: 'json'` to understand. The request/response may be succeeding, only to `error` when jQuery attempts to parse the response. (What is the value of the 3rd argument – `errorThrown` – to jQuery's `error` handler?)

Comment: @Akshay I have a post router in backend if you asking that.

Comment: @Enix Nothing is wrong with request. It works perfectly. Only ajax request has problem

Comment: @JonathanLonowski I was first testing on Postman. Those `send()` were for postman. I removed them. 3rd value is "Bad Request"

Comment: You mentioned in a previous comment "*but still request shows `err.message` and it is `undefined`*." The 1st argument to `error` with `jQuery.ajax()` isn't an `Error` instance; it's a [`jqXHR`](https://api.jquery.com/Types/#jqXHR). Try logging `err.responseText`.

Comment: `err.responseText` shows my content of `error.ejs`.

Answer (score 1):

I have removed `dataType: 'json'`and `contentType: "application/json"`and ajax request succeeded. I still don't know why but it worked after removing them.

Comment: The response is not JSON.  See other answer.  Also [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18701282/what-is-content-type-and-datatype-in-an-ajax-request)

Answer (score 0):

`dataType` refers to the expected response from the server - see [HERE](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).  If the response is not JSON, remove `dataType: 'json'` from the ajax function, and jQuery will make an intelligent guess.

Comment: See: https://jsfiddle.net/ema79prk/1/ is working. Change `dataType: 'json'` to `dataType: 'xml'` and you'll get a `parseerror`

Answer (score 0):

The ajax client expects your response MIME type as 'json', however you provided a plain text 'okay' as response.

If you still need to send json as a response, you can make use of [res.type](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.type) change your backend like this:

```
router.post('/', function (req, res) {
    if (typeof req.body.contactName === 'undefined' || typeof req.body.contactEmail === 'undefined' ||
        typeof req.body.contactSubject === 'undefined' || typeof req.body.contactMessage === 'undefined' ||
        !validator.isEmail(req.body.contactEmail)) {
        return res.status(400).type('json').send({"result": "error"});
    }
    mail.sendMail(req.body.contactName, req.body.contactEmail, req.body.contactSubject, req.body.contactMessage);
    return res.status(200).type('json').send({"result":"okay"});
});
```

Then your frontend should work as expected. For most of the case, you don't need to specify `dataType`, because ajax could determine the mime type automatically base on your server response.