# Controller does not get json data

Tags: c#, jquery, json, post, model-view-controller

I'm trying to pass json data from view to controller but controller getting null all the time I tried every thing to resolve this issue but didn't find any solution here is my controller and json data

```
$("#ex_save").on("click",function() {
        var array = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
        var json = JSON.stringify(array);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Equipment/BulkUpdate",
            data: { jsonCollection : json },
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function () { 
                console.log("Saved"); 
            },
            error: function (e) {
                console.log(e);
            }
        });
    });
```

this my ajax method to pass data to controller.
and here is my controller to get that data :-

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult BulkUpdate(string jsonCollection)
    {
        try
        {
            return View();
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

here is the json what I'm passing 
[image]

here is the error :-
[image]

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're sending JSON within JSON instead of just using the standard ModelBinder? Seems like you're just adding complexity for no reason except giving yourself more work.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I have editable table that I'm showing on view so user can edit it and press submit to save but I've pagination so it only pass first page data to controller  collection so I tried this way.

Comment: You're passing a string and expecting a string, but your $.ajax call is telling it that it's actually json (when it's not, it's a string).  Change the contentType to string or remove it.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/18701357/2181514

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan nope not worked still getting this error _Invalid JSON primitive: jsonCollection._ I changed dataType _json_ to _text_

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan not getting value at controller but error is resolved.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do this

```
$("#ex_save").on("click",function() {
        var array = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
        var jsonData =  {jsonCollection : array};
        var postJson = JSON.stringify(jsonData);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Equipment/BulkUpdate",
            data: postJson,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function () { 
                console.log("Saved"); 
            },
            error: function (e) {
                console.log(e);
            }
        });
    });
```

What you were doing is that you have used `JSON.stringify()` to convert the JSON in `array` variable and then you were assigning this to the new JSON object `{ jsonCollection : json }` as POST request body. So it is a valid json object like 
`{'name':'test1', 'age':'12'}`
 then jQuery might not send it as json data but instead serialize it to `name=test1&age=12`
 thus you get the error
 `"Invalid JSON primitive: name"`

And in your case, `"Invalid JSON primitive: jsonCollection"`. So try using above code.

Comment: it helped now not getting error but still not getting collection values at controller too.

Comment: But i think the problem here was to resolve the error. Now it is your side of workouts to check the response data or request payload in the server and debug.

Comment: I also think that it should be green marked as the answer solves the error.

Comment: can you please mark it green or if you need anything else from my side to improve the answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#ex_save").on("click",function() {
    var array = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
    var jsonData =  {jsonCollection : array};
    var postJson = JSON.stringify(jsonData);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Equipment/BulkUpdate",
        data: postJson,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function () { 
            console.log("Saved"); 
        },
        error: function (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    });
});
```

And instead of getting string at controller try to get ICollection

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult BulkUpdate(ICollection<your_class_type> jsonCollection)
{
    try
    {
        return View();
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```