# AJAX adds parenthesis to my data

Tags: jquery, ajax, mongodb

My AJAX call is sending the following data:

```
[{"type": "paragraph","subtype": "p","label": "Paragraph"}]
```

However when I print the data received on the console at the back end I get this:

```
{ '[{"type": "paragraph","subtype": "p","label": "Paragraph"}]': '' }
```

Please let me know if there is way to prevent this from happening as the data sent via AJAX is to be inserted into my `MongoDB`.

Thanks to all in advance!

Comment: If you can show us the full code, it might be helpful.

Comment: That's actually a lack of a "body parser" or otherwise forgetting to add `application/json` to the `Content-Type` of the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set `contentType` in your ajax like below:-

```
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
```

Reference:-[What is content-type and datatype in an AJAX request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18701282/what-is-content-type-and-datatype-in-an-ajax-request)