# i used ajax call and send "itemShape" as data but in url page it's show Undefined index: itemShape

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Hello i used ajax function send data:**itemShape** and when i directly run url page or service page it's show error:

> Notice: Undefined index: itemShape in
>   C:\wamp64\www\inventory_software\get_item_types_dhk.php on line 5

please someone help how to solve this issue. i am going to upload pic of error for better understanding:

[image]

here is the url page code:

```
<?php
include 'config.php';


    $itemShape = $_POST["itemShape"];

    $mysql="SELECT product_id,item_shape from product_table where item_name="."'$itemShape'";
    //echo $mysql;
    $count=0;
    $myquantity = $conn->query($mysql);
    $new_array=array();
if ($myquantity->num_rows > 0) {
        while($myrow = $myquantity->fetch_assoc()) {
            $quantity_sum['count']=$count+1;
            $quantity_price['item_name']= $myrow['item_shape'];
            $quantity_price['item_id']= $myrow['product_id'];
            array_push($new_array,$quantity_price);


        }
    }
    $new_item=array_merge($quantity_sum,$new_array);
    echo json_encode($new_item);
?>
```

this is the ajax method which is used:

```
$('#item_name').change(function(){
        //alert();
        var Item_Name=$("#item_name option:selected").text();
        alert("item_name");
         $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         url: 'get_item_types_dhk.php', 
         data: {itemShape: Item_Name},
         dataType: "json",
         success: function(data){
```

Someone please help me how to solve this issue

Comment: you need to `post` the  `itemShape` `data` to that page otherwise you will get `undefined index` only

Comment: Get the request body using `file_get_contents('php://input')`.

Comment: @JYoThI sorry i can't understand would you please explain. actually this is my first time work on ajax..

Comment: If by `when i directly run url page` you mean you are putting the address of the PHP script into the browser address and runngin it. You are not setting the POST data when you do that

Comment: oh i got it @RiggsFolly... 
you mean i have to change value???

Comment: While tesing like that you could change `$_POST` to `$_GET` and do `http://example.com/get_item_types_dhk.php?itemShape=100`

Comment: @RiggsFolly it's show nothing. would you please check it.

Comment: I assume you are not actually using `example.com` right?

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes dear instead of example.com i used my folder name. 
i there any other change i used when i run that???
i mean i want to comment anything in PHP code.

Comment: Do `print_r($_POST);` and see what it returns.

Comment: Add [error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php/845025#845025) to the
top of your file(s) _while testing_ right after your opening PHP tag for example
`<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to see if it yields anything.

Comment: @RiggsFolly it's show nothing.. can we discuss this on email please.. i really need to solve this

Comment: @Fanckush it's not working ???

Comment: Are you using `mysqli_` or `PDO`?

Comment: @radsinstallation check my answer it should solve your problem

Comment: @RiggsFolly i am using mysqli

Comment: Give us your request header, that will show what you are sending

Comment: @mukund basically i am working on localhost so i used : localhost/inventory_software/get_item_types_dhk.php

Comment: @radsinstallation thats true but if you look at network in your browser debugger, you can see the request and response headers. So looking at your response header we can get idea what may preventing your post

Comment: Try this in ur php to check what you are receiving: `var_dump(file_get_contents("php://input"));`

Answer (score 0):

You are sending your data as a json without setting `contentType` to json.

**Solution 1:**
send you data in the default format:

Instead of `data: {itemShape: Item_Name},`

do `data: "itemShape=" +  Item_Name,`

**Solution 2:**
set content type for json:

Setting `dataType` to json is meant fo the data **received** and not the data you are sending; for setting the data type of the data you are **sending** you use `contentType` like this:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'get_item_types_dhk.php',   
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", //set data to be json
  // data: {itemShape: Item_Name}, // before
  data : JSON.stringify({itemShape: Item_Name}), //after
  dataType: "json", // this is the returned data type...
  success: function(data)
```

Read a more detailed answer the difference between `dataType` and `contentType` over here [What is content-type and datatype in an AJAX request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18701282/what-is-content-type-and-datatype-in-an-ajax-request)

Comment: The default content type is `"application/json; charset=utf-8"`

Comment: @JYoThI even if it is, he is not converting the json to a string with `JSON.stringify `, plus it is better to explicitly set the contextType to reduce the chances of errors

Comment: @JYoThI i just looked it up to be sure and according to jQuery documentation [link](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/): `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'` is the default contentType