# How to use AJAX for my form

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to understand how to send two arrays to my php script using AJAX, initially i was simply allowing the page to reload.

I have started implementing the `AJAX` call however i am just confused on how to send the two arrays. Also how i would use the data in my php file.   This is what i have so far :

```
<head>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
</head>

<form method="post" action="submit.php" >

<input id="name" type="text" name="name[]" class=""/>
<input id="amount" type="text" name="amount[]" class=""/>

<button type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block sendTheForm" name="sending" >Submit</button>

</form>

<script>

$(document).on('click', '.sendTheForm', function(){  

    $.ajax({  
       url:"submit.php",  
       method:"POST",  
       data:{},  
       success:function(data){

            swal({
               title: "Submitted",
               text: "sucessfully sent",
               icon: "success",
            });

        }  
     });  
  }

});
</script>
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated and hopefully i will learn a thing or two!

Answer (score 0):

```js
var nameArrays = [];
function getArray(){
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("#form input[name='name[]']");
for(var i=0; i<inputs.length; i++)
nameArrays.push(inputs[i].value)
console.log(nameArrays)
}
```

```html
<form id="form">
<input type="text" name="name[]" value="Name1" /> 
<input type="text" name="name[]" value="Name2" /> 
<input type="button" onclick="getArray()" />
</form>
```

```
var array1 = ['a','b', 'c'],
array2 = ['d', 'e', 'e'];

$(document).on('click', '.sendTheForm', function(){  

        $.ajax({  
             url:"submit.php",  
             method:"POST",  
             data:{ array1 : array1, array2: array2},  
             success:function(data){

                swal({
                    title: "Submitted",
                    text: "sucessfully sent",
                    icon: "success",
                });

             }  
        });  
   }

 });
```

Ps. If you want to send the form data as `JSON` you can use [Jquery serialize](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) like

```
 $.ajax({  
             url:"submit.php",  
             method:"POST",  
             data: $("#formId").serialize(),  
             success:function(data){}
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, how would i grab the two arrays in my form name[] and amount[] and send it off? I would like to avoid sending by JSON if possible

Comment: I've added a `snippet` to show how you can grab that array. Now you can do anything with it. send it as json and if you don't want that, just change the `contentType`. You can read more about datatype and contentType [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18701282/what-is-content-type-and-datatype-in-an-ajax-request)

Answer (score 0):

With `jquery`, On your `$.ajax` call try like this using `serialize()`. See more about [serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) and [serializeArray](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/)

```
       $.ajax({  
             url:"submit.php",  
             method:"POST",  
             data: $("form").serialize(),
             contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
             dataType: 'json',
             success:function(data){
             // do what you want to do after ajax success
             }  
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, is there a way in which i can just send it off without using JSON?

Comment: just remove that `contentType`