# jQuery process Javascriptobject as in Ajax

Tags: jquery, json, eval

I'm indirectly using a jQuery ajax call to send data to my server.
In my data is a reference to a function (getName) which get called bij jQuery and the return value is sended through ajax (sendDataPOST).

So this works, except the data that's being send is a querystring (id=500&name=test) and I want to send JSON.

So I added a JSON.stringify over the data so it gets converted to JSON, but as a result the getName function isn't called anymore and the variable is ignored. ({id:500})

```
var data = {
     id: 500,
     name: getName
};

function getName(){
   return "test";
}

function sendDataPOST(){
    $.ajax({
      url: "/test.html",
      data: data
   });
}

function sendDataJSON(){
    $.ajax({
      url: "/test.html",
      data: JSON.stringify(data)
   });
}
```

Is there a way to let jQuery execute the function before I convert it to JSON ?
And does somebody has a name or a reference too the jQuery docs about the method I'm using ?

And by using the ajax call indirectly, I mean the use off Kendo where I'm limited to the changes I can make to the ajax configuration.

Comment: You've got a lot of problems here, but you might find this article interesting in terms of calling functions when a property is accessed: [how to use javascript Object.defineProperty](//stackoverflow.com/q/18524652)

Comment: I mean, you could always do `data.name()` in your `sendDataJSON` method before making the ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

In order to change the type of data you're sending you should set `contentType` parameter to `application/json; charset=UTF-8` as it defaults to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8` :

```
    function sendDataPOST(){
        $.ajax({
          url: "/test.html",
          data: data,
          contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
       });
    }
```

See the [reference](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) and check out the [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18701282/what-is-content-type-and-datatype-in-an-ajax-request).