# Can't send array data to REST endpoint

Tags: django, ajax, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am using Django REST framework. I have a model that looks like this:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title       = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)
    content     = HTMLField()
    created_at  = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    authors     = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

With an api view and serializer that looks like this:

```
class CreateStoryApiView(CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = PostSerializer

class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('title', 'content', 'authors')
```

Going to the actual endpoint, I can actually submit successfully. I am trying to use Ajax to take the details and submit the data to the endpoint, but for some reason I am always getting a 400 bad request error. If I remove the authors field, I don't have that error. Here's how the Ajax request looks like:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/api/save-post/',
    data: {
    "csrfmiddlewaretoken": getCookie('csrftoken'),
    "title": "dasf",
    "desct": "dasf",
    "content": "fdasf",
    "authors": [1,2]
    },
    success: function (msg) {
        console.log(msg);
    }
});
```

I get a 400 bad request when I try this Ajax request. Why can't I submit my array successfully? I've tried `"authors[]": [1,2]` and `"authors": "[1,2]"` and a lot of other combinations, but it seems like nothing is working for some reason. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What error/response are you getting from API?

Comment: @JPG I'm just getting a 400 bad request. When I go to the Django REST endpoint and enter my data there, it works successfully and I can enter the authors as an array

Comment: I need to know the ***error response***. The 400 status code cloud be raised due to several reasons

Comment: @JPG Where can I find the error response?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know. May be in your *Network* section in the browser

Comment: @JPG Ahhh I see, you taught me something. The error response is: `{"authors":["This list may not be empty."]}`

Comment: cool.... Can you add more info regarding that ***POST*** request? request payload (from the browser)

Comment: @JPG `title: dasf
desct: dasf
content: fdasf
authors[]: 1
authors[]: 2` This is how it looks when I do `"authors": [1,2]`

Comment: That's the problem. What about the content type? (browser)

Comment: @JPG  `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8`

Comment: specify the `content-type` in your ajax request as `application/json` ref : [this so post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18701282/what-is-content-type-and-datatype-in-an-ajax-request)

Comment: @JPG I did this, and now my error response is: `{"detail":"JSON parse error - Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)"}` and the payload is: `csrfmiddlewaretoken=bmiehYH9PnJrIbXA8TLluoKblrnEnjc6fpYeHMLS0tiH2I8V1jeYh97e0UlbFR43&title=dasf&desct=dasf&content=fdasf&authors%5B%5D=1&authors%5B%5D=2`

Comment: you may need to do JsonStringyfy

Comment: @JPG Exact same error, but now the payload is: `csrfmiddlewaretoken=bmiehYH9PnJrIbXG8BLluoKblrnEnjc6fpYeHMLS0tiH2I8V1jeYh97e0UlbFR43&title=dasf&desct=dasf&content=fdasf&authors=%5B1%2C2%5D`

Answer (score -1):

check your django settings.py file.
You need correct configuration of  next parameters to post a request from another server.

```
 CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
    'localhost',
    'your-domain.com',
    '127.0.0.1',
    '127.0.0.1:8080'
)

CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = (
    'your-domain.com',
)

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True

CORS_EXPOSE_HEADERS = [
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin',
'Access-Control-Allow-Headers'
]

CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True

CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = (
    'accept',
    'accept-encoding',
    'authorization',
    'content-type',
    'cache-control',
    'dnt',
    'origin',
    'user-agent',
    'x-csrftoken',
    'x-requested-with',
)

CORS_ALLOW_METHODS = (
    'DELETE',
    'GET',
    'OPTIONS',
    'PATCH',
    'POST',
    'PUT',
)
```

I suspect that is because of it

Comment: This isnt from another server.