# Ajax post zero to controller

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core, asp.net-ajax

I'm trying to `POST` an int with `Ajax` to my controller

**Js**

```
<script>
    function FillCity() {
        var provinceId = $(provinces).val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "FillCity",
            type: "POST",
            data: { id: provinceId },
            dataType: "json",
            traditional: true,
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (data) {
                $("#cities").html(""); // clear before appending new list
                $.each(data, function (i, city) {
                    $("#cities").append(
                        $('<option></option>').val(city.Id).html(city.Name));
                });
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

code in my controller :

```cs
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult FillCity(int id)
{
    var cities = _context.City.Where(c => c.ProvinceId == 5);
    return Json(cities);
}
```

but it always post 0 as id, I tried digits instead of provinceId, but it rtills send 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create an class that have a `Id` Property.

```
public class ProvinceIdDto 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

replace `int id` with `ProvinceIdDto model` in action

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult FillCity(ProvinceIdDto model)
{
    var cities = _context.City.Where(c => c.ProvinceId == model.Id);
    return Json(cities);
}
```

replace `{ id: provinceId }` with `JSON.stringify({ Id: provinceId }),`

```
<script>
    function FillCity() {
        var provinceId = $(provinces).val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "FillCity",
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify({ Id: provinceId }),
            dataType: "json",
            traditional: true,
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (data) {
                $("#cities").html(""); // clear before appending new list
                $.each(data, function (i, city) {
                    $("#cities").append(
                        $('<option></option>').val(city.Id).html(city.Name));
                });
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Another options is you can replace `HttpPost` method with `HttpGet` and pass id to action like this.

Change `type: "POST",` to `type: "GET",`

```
<script>
    function FillCity() {
        var provinceId = $(provinces).val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "FillCity?id="+provinceId,//<-- NOTE THIS
            type: "GET",//<-- NOTE THIS
            dataType: "json",
            traditional: true,
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (data) {
                $("#cities").html(""); // clear before appending new list
                $.each(data, function (i, city) {
                    $("#cities").append(
                        $('<option></option>').val(city.Id).html(city.Name));
                });
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

**C#**

```cs
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult FillCity(int id)
{
    var cities = _context.City.Where(c => c.ProvinceId == id);
    return Json(cities);
}
```

Comment: thank you again because the second solution was correct too

Answer (score 0):

when you do `{ id: provinceId  }` you are creating an object with property `id`

in your controller you are just expecting an id. You will need to ether:

**A** pass it as a query parameter `url: "FillCity?id=" + provinceId`

**B** create an object to be parsed from the request body.

```
public class Payload {
   public int Id {get;set;}
}
```

and use it like this
`public ActionResult FillCity([FromBody] Payload payload)`

Comment: still post null:(

Answer (score 0):

Can you verify this statement has a value:

```
var provinceId = $(provinces).val();
```

It's possible that isn't finding what you are looking for, and because you have the type int as a parameter, it defaults it to "0".

You shouldn't need to change it to a GET and your MVC method is fine as is.  You can see from [JQuery's own sample it should work](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

```
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
})
  .done(function( msg ) {
    alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
  });
```

I think it might not be finding the input field successfully.

Comment: I said that I tested with digit like 5 and still doesnt work

Comment: Try removing traditional: true because I do something similar to what you have but don't have that.  Also per the attached link, you may want to use dataType, not contentType, since you are returning JSON: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18701282/what-is-content-type-and-datatype-in-an-ajax-request/18701357#:~:text=3%20Answers&text=contentType%20is%20the%20type%20of,%2C%20html%20%2C%20text%20%2C%20etc.