# data not binded successfully in ASP.NET Core 2.2 when calling an action by an ajax post with data type JSON

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.2

I checked similar questions many others posted and tried different solutions with not success.

I have an asp.net core 2.2 web app (controllers, not rest-api) and I added to startup a configuration for json formatter:

```
AddJsonOptions(options => options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver());
```

Into my View I do this:

```
function crearObjetoTramiteRequisito() {
        var tramiteGeneralId = retornarItemGridTramitesGenerales().Id;
        var tramitesRequisitos = [];
        $.each(arrayDocumentoSeleccionado, function (index, value) {
            tramitesRequisitos.push({ Id: 0, TramiteDocumentoId: value, TramiteGeneralId: tramiteGeneralId});
        });
        
        return tramitesRequisitos;
    }

function guardarTramitesRequisitos() {
        onCloseWindowRequisitos();
        var requestData = crearObjetoTramiteRequisito();
       
        $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("CrearRequisitos", "ConfiguracionTramitesGenerales")",
            type: 'POST',
            headers: {
                "RequestVerificationToken": antiForgeryTokens()
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {'requestData': JSON.stringify(requestData) },
            success: function (result) {
                console.log(result);
            },
            error: function (e) {
                console.log(e);
            }
        });
    }
```

I expect a JSON array into the controller parameter.

[image]

The ViewModel:

```
public class TramiteRequisitoViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int TramiteDocumentoId { get; set; }
    public int TramiteGeneralId { get; set; }
}
```

The controller is:

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public JsonResult CrearRequisitos (List<TramiteRequisitoViewModel> requestData)
    {
        int x = 0;
```

The requestData parameter comes with 0 elements.

No matter if I use [FromBody] param attribute or use array JSON objects instead of stringify them, don't work, neither using contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"

Comment: have you checked the ContentType in your browser?should be ``contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"``

Comment: I used that with not success, since ContentType is the response data type from the server to the client. I edited the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ContentType` is the request dataType, `dataType` is the response dataType, you can refer to his [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18701357/11965297).

And the data should be in this format `data: JSON.stringify(requestData)`

A simple Test as below:

**Script:**

```
<button id="btn" onclick="guardarTramitesRequisitos()" value="Submit"></button>

@section scripts{ 
    <script>
    function crearObjetoTramiteRequisito() {
        var tramitesRequisitos = [];
        tramitesRequisitos.push({ Id: 0, TramiteDocumentoId: 1, TramiteGeneralId: 1 });
        tramitesRequisitos.push({ Id: 0, TramiteDocumentoId: 2, TramiteGeneralId: 1 });
        console.log(tramitesRequisitos);
        return tramitesRequisitos;
    }

    function guardarTramitesRequisitos() {
    
        var requestData = crearObjetoTramiteRequisito();

        $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("CrearRequisitos", "ConfiguracionTramitesGenerales")",
            type: 'POST',
            contentType:'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: JSON.stringify(requestData),
            success: function (result) {
                console.log(result);
            },
            error: function (e) {
                console.log(e);
            }
        });
    }
    </script>
}
```

**Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult CrearRequisitos([FromBody]List<TramiteRequisitoViewModel> requestData)
{
    return Json(requestData);
}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change this
 `data: {'requestData': JSON.stringify(requestData) }` 
to
 `data: { JSON.stringify(requestData) }`