# Incorrect encoding of contentType in AJAX Call for MVC Action

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to call an AJAX function to transfer some `JSON data` (Roughly 38Kb in size) which will be cast onto a `List<ModelClass>` in the `Controller Action` for other processors.

**(Simplified) _oRecords Data Format before AJAX transfer** - `console.log(JSON.stringify(_oRecords));`

```
[{{"sn":2208,"timeStampMarker":"","Id":0,"Data1":1,"Data2":2,"Data3":3},{"sn":2209,"timeStampMarker":"","Id":0,"Data1":1,"Data2":2,"Data3":3},{"sn":2210,"timeStampMarker":"","Id":0,"Data1":1,"Data2":2,"Data3":3},}]
```

**(Simplified) Data Format on Controller Action** - F12 Network Payload

```
records=%5B%7B%22sn%22%3A2208%2C%22timeStampMarker%22%3A%22%22%2C%22Id%22%3A0%2C%22Data1%22%3A1%2C%2Data2%22%3A2%2C%22Data3%22%3A3%7D%2C%7B%22 sn%22%3A2159%2C%22timeStampMarker%22%3A%22%22%2C%22Id%22%3A0%2C%22Data1%22%3A1%2C%2Data2%22%3A2%2C%22Data3%22%3A3%7D%2C%7B%22 sn%22%3A2159%2C%22timeStampMarker%22%3A%22%22%2C%22Id%22%3A0%2C%22Data1%22%3A1%2C%2Data2%22%3A2%2C%22Data3%22%3A3%7D%2C%7B%22
```

Essentially, the special characters such as `'[', '{', ','` are encoded wrongly by `contentType` option of the AJAX call. Following this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18701282/what-is-content-type-and-datatype-in-an-ajax-request), the above result was received after configuring the AJAX call as below:

**Ajax Call COnfiguration - View**

```
$.ajax({
    url: '../CSV/SaveDataFoo/',
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: { records: JSON.stringify(_oRecords) },
    dataType: "json"
});
```

**Controller**

```
public JsonResult SaveDataFoo(List<DataModelClass> records)
{
     //Does some things with `records` List<T>

     return Json(null);
}
```

Due to the incorrect transfer, `records`'s Count is [0] (as expected). Is there any other AJAX configuration or perhaps further manipulation of `_oRecords` I can do to fix this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just use `data: JSON.stringify(_oRecords)`

Comment: Thanks! Payload is correct, but now the `records` is `null`, is it because I'm trying to cast a List of List into it? But it should just be cast as multiple records stacked right?

Comment: You might need to add `[FromBody]` to the `records` arg.

Comment: Thanks! It works now - strange, I thought I had tried this combo before :/ Do you mind posting as an Answer. Otherwise, I will Update the Post with the right Config/take this post down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things here...

1. To send a JSON request body with jQuery, don't nest the data in an object. jQuery will treat that as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

   ```js
   $.ajax({
     url: "../CSV/SaveDataFoo/",
     method: "POST",
     contentType: "application/json",
     processData: false,
     data: JSON.stringify(_oRecords),
     dataType: "json"
   });
   ```
2. To tell your controller action to parse the data out of the response body, use the [`[FromBody]` attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api#using-frombody)

   ```c#
   public JsonResult SaveDataFoo([FromBody] List<DataModelClass> records)
   ```