# how to display AJAX Wikipedia API call in HTML modal

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have 2 PHP scripts like so which use the country name to bring up relevant wikipedia articles via an API

```
<?php

// Display errors is set to on and should be removed for production
    ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

// Timing script execution
    $executionStartTime = microtime(true);

    $url='https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=search&format=json&origin=*&srsearch=' . $_REQUEST['countryName'];
// Curl object is initiated
    $ch = curl_init();
    
//Curl_setopt() takes three parameters(Curl instance to use, setting you want to change, value you want to use for that setting)    

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    $result=curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

    $decode = json_decode($result, true);   
    

    $output['status']['code'] = "200";
    $output['status']['name'] = "ok";
    $output['status']['description'] = "success";
    $output['status']['returnedIn'] = intval((microtime(true) - $executionStartTime) * 1000) . " ms";
    $output['result'] = $decode;

    
    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');

    echo json_encode($output); 

?>
```

```
<?php

// Display errors is set to on and should be removed for production
    ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

// Timing script execution
    $executionStartTime = microtime(true);

    $url='https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=info&inprop=url&origin=*&format=json&pageids=' . $_REQUEST['id'];
// Curl object is initiated
    $ch = curl_init();
    
//Curl_setopt() takes three parameters(Curl instance to use, setting you want to change, value you want to use for that setting)    

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    $result=curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

    $decode = json_decode($result, true);   
    

    $output['status']['code'] = "200";
    $output['status']['name'] = "ok";
    $output['status']['description'] = "success";
    $output['status']['returnedIn'] = intval((microtime(true) - $executionStartTime) * 1000) . " ms";
    $output['result'] = $decode;

    
    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');

    echo json_encode($output); 

?>
```

I have then attempted a JS AJAX function call them

```
function getWikiSearch() {
    let countryName = $('#innerSelect option:selected').text()
    if (countryName == 'United Kingdom') {
    countryName = 'UK'}

    let ids = "";
    let links = [];
    let results = [];

    $.ajax({
        method: 'GET',
        url: "assets/php/getWiki.php",
        data: {
               countryName: countryName
                },
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function(result) {
            console.log(result)
        
            results = result.query.search;
            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                if (results[i + 1] != null) {
                    ids += results[i].pageid + "|";
                } else {
                    ids += results[i].pageid;
                }
            }
            console.log(ids)
                $.ajax({
                method: 'GET',
                url: "assets/php/getWikiID.php",
                data: {
                       id: ids
                        },
                contentType: 'application/json',
                success: function(result) {
                    console.log(result)
                for (i in result.query.pages) {
                links.push(result.query.pages[i].fullurl);                  
                    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "";
                            for (let i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                                if (i < 3) {
                                    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += "<br><br><a href='" + links[i] + "'target='_blank'>" + results[i].title + "</a><br>" + results[i].snippet + "... Click title to read full article.";

                            }}
                }}})
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            console.log(jqXHR)
                            console.log(textStatus)
                            console.log(errorThrown)
                                }
                    })
        }
```

My console is showing that the api calls are returning the appropriate data, but I cant seem to get the data to fit my modal like this example.

[image]

Instead, my modal is just blank with a search bar and button which don't do anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set the contentType in your ajax requests instead of the dataType(see [contentType vs dataType](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18701282/what-is-content-type-and-datatype-in-an-ajax-request). You're receiving json not sending it.
Change

```
contentType: 'application/json',
```

to

```
dataType: 'json',
```

Also, you are trying to access the json data returned incorrectly, you're missing a `result` in your attempt to access the data.

```
var results = result.result.query.search;
...

    for (let i in result.result.query.pages) {
```

Comment: Thank you, I've made your suggested changes but still the modal is empty :(

Comment: Check developer tools console for errors and the network tab for to see the results of your requests

Comment: Yes I have, but unfortunately no luck in solving the issue